# Issue with accessing the attribute value of composite array in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TYPE names AS (
    "name" varchar(32767),
     seq bigint);

CREATE FUNCTION public.show_array(OUT array_attr public.names[])
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
AS $function$
DECLARE

    m varchar[];
BEGIN
  array_attr := ARRAY(SELECT ROW('NAME' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER(), ROW_NUMBER() OVER())::public.names 
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T  
                        LIMIT 4
                   );

  RAISE NOTICE ' array_lower(array_attr, 1): %', array_lower(array_attr, 1);
  RAISE NOTICE ' array_upper(array_attr, 1): %', array_upper(array_attr, 1);
   FOR i IN array_lower(array_attr, 1) .. array_upper(array_attr, 1)
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'name: %', array_attr[i][1];
      RAISE NOTICE 'seq: %', array_attr[i][2];
   END LOOP;   

   FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY array_attr
   loop
      RAISE NOTICE 'array values(%,%,%,%)',m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4];
   END LOOP;

--*/
END;
$function$;
```

I am loading an array of composite custom type and want to verify the values loaded by displaying them via standard output.
When executing the above function as: select public.show_array();
I get this output:

```
00000:  array_lower(array_attr, 1): 1
00000:  array_upper(array_attr, 1): 4
00000: name: <NULL>
00000: seq: <NULL>
00000: name: <NULL>
00000: seq: <NULL>
00000: name: <NULL>
00000: seq: <NULL>
00000: name: <NULL>
00000: seq: <NULL>
00000: array values((NAME1,1),(NAME2,2),(NAME3,3),(NAME4,4))
```

FOR m SLICE loop shows the values in the array, 
however the references to array attributes show NULL values.

My question is why, and how do we access the individual array attributes values if this method does not work:
    RAISE NOTICE 'name: %', array_attr[i][1];
    RAISE NOTICE 'seq: %', array_attr[i][2];

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the columns of the type in a different way:

```
(array_attr[i]).name
(array_attr[i]).seq
```